# Identifying the implied gender of nouns

Tags: nouns, pronouns, grammatical-gender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Referring to objects as “she”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3178/referring-to-objects-as-she)

English officially does not have genders like German or other languages; for example, a chair is an *it*, not a *he* or *she*.

However, when you refer to a spaceship you say *she*, and you say *daughter molecule*  in DNA replication narration, which implies a molecule is a she.

Where can you find out the “hidden” gender of nouns?  Is there a rule to go by? Why not say “son molecule”?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Referring to objects as “she”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3178/referring-to-objects-as-she), [Using “she” with gender-neutral nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77350/using-she-with-gender-neutral-nouns)

Comment: @RegDwight: The first link is a dup that really does address OP's concerns here, but I think the second is more about (off-topic, imho) interpretation of poetic usage in song lyrics.

Comment: Whorf talks about English covert gender in one of the articles in _Language, Mind, and Reality_. Ships, airplanes, large weapons, and unknown cats, for instance, are _she_, while unknown dogs are _he_. As the previous owner of a female dog and a male cat, I'm here to tell you that that's what people often do.